# Settle in England

Tags: united-kingdom, paperwork, legal

I'm Italian and want to stay in England for more than three months, but even if I get a job, I'm not sure the employers will emit some certificate showing that I've worked there (this is the worst case but I need to contemplate it, cause I'm first travelling using workaway, where there are no 'service certificates' I guess.)

1. What exactly happens after three months staying in England? Do we
   need to go to some officers or anything like that to stay legally?
2. Do we need any document besides our passport to settle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre-Brexit, the answer is "no".  There is no obligation to register with anyone after three months (or any other time period).  (You will need a National Insurance Number to work, and you may choose to register with a doctor, but that is your choice.)

You also don't need to "get residence".  As https://www.gov.uk/uk-residence-eu-citizens says

> You do not currently need to apply for a document to prove you can live in the UK unless: [list of exceptions that probably do not apply]

---

Post Brexit the answer is that you will have to apply for [pre-settled status](https://www.gov.uk/settled-status-eu-citizens-families) before the end of 2020.  The pilot trials of this have not been encouraging, but make sure you keep pay slips and copies of your rental agreement (to prove you are working, and when from).

Comment: @santimirandarp Information on how to apply for a NINO is here https://www.gov.uk/apply-national-insurance-number

Comment: @Santimirandarp AFAIK the approach to permission to stay is explained in the policy document linked to in Martin Bonner’s answer ie you’d have to apply for pre-settled status. As with any immigration-related applications I imagine there is a (small) risk of refusal, depending on individual circumstances. Possibly the bigger question is: ‘what is attracting you to the U.K. and will you want to stay longer?’ No-one really knows what the effect of Brexit will be on eg the employment market, living costs, housing etc. About the only thing it won’t affect for sure is the weather!!

Comment: @santimirandarp This is verging off topic for the comments here: If you have applied for, and been granted, pre-settled status you will be able to remain indefinitely with a European passport (unless Perfidious Albion changes the rules again).  If you have not applied for pre-settled status by end of 2020, you will have to leave.

Comment: @Traveller  Thanks both, really. I see. After reading the links you post I'll possibly make another post, possibly.

Comment: Uhmm, I've read the article. I think I should have said that I'm argentinian with an italian passport. It is not the same than being italian, it seems...(I supposed it was) @Traveller

Comment: @santimirandarp What do you mean "you are Argentinian with an Italian passport?"  If you have an Italian passport, you must be an Italian citizen.  You may also be an Argentinian citizen, but you have all the rights of any other Italian citizen.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I'm not born in Italy, although I have the passport. I supposed that this extract: 'You do not currently need to apply for a document to prove you can live in the UK unless:
    you’re an extended family member of someone from the European Economic Area (EEA) or Switzerland' was relevant. Maybe I misunderstood it.

Comment: @santimirandarp You misunderstood.  You are not "an extended family member" (parent, grandchild etc) of an EEA citizen, you *are* an EEA citizen.

Comment: To be super clear: the country where you were born doesn't matter -- what matters is from what country do you hold a passport.